# setting memory limit in docker-compose is giving error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to set the memory limit in my docker-compose file in a non-swarm mode. So here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.5"

services:
 model:
    image: ...
    container_name: ...
    env_file: ./.env
    command: ...
    network_mode: host
    mem_reservation: 30000000
    ports:
        - ...
```

but it complains as follows

```
ERROR: The Compose file '././docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.model: 'mem_reservation'
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you limit memory. You have to limit it by adding the limit under the deploy subsection. Check this yaml for mongo.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2g
```

Run it with

```
docker-compose --compatibility -d up
```